# Using container view in ios with swift

Tags: ios

I just want to reuse the `ProgressView` and 3 `UILable`s from following image. I will reuse these in many Views. That's why I am trying to create it as a `Container`.

[image]

I combined these as a container and try the following code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    internal var progressViewController : ProgressViewController ;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

and `ProgressViewController` is

```
class ProgressViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblVLow: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMedium: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblVHigh: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
}
```

And while trying to run this code, I am getting following error,

```
fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented,
```

I don't know this is correct way or not. But I want that box as a reusable. Any idea or help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass parameters to ProgressViewController, you should do it through `prepareForSegue`. Something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ProgressViewEmbed" {
         let dest = segue.destinationViewController as ProgressViewController;
         dest.strVLow = "Hello"
    }

}
```

So, remove the `internal var progressViewController` and remove all the `init` functions. And then pass parameters through non-IB variables and then assign these values to IB values in `ProgressViewController.viewDidLoad()`. Something like the following:

```
class ProgressViewController {
    // IB Outlets
    var strVLow : String!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        if let str = strVLow {
            self.lblVLow.text = str;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to change the Embed Segue identifier, go to storyboard and click on the embed segue and change the identifier to anything you need to: [image]

EDIT: Reconstructed the answer completely.

Comment: I have removed these code from `ProgressViewController`, again I am getting same error. When I add `internal var progressViewController : ProgressViewController ;` in `ViewController` these codes are automatically added.

Comment: Remove it from `ViewController`

Comment: If I removed I am getting `class ViewController has no initializers` error.

Comment: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on `dest.lblVLow.text = "Hello";`

Comment: As I said, this was just a test and you shouldn't try to change the value of UIView when preparing for segue. You would rather send `String`, object, array etc and then do the change in `ProgressViewController.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I reconstructed the answer to make everything clear.

Answer (score 1):

The UIViewController adopts the NSCoding protocol, which requires an initWithCoder: method, or init(coder:) as it becomes in Swift. To meet these needs you need to comment out the fatalError or delete it. The property progressViewController then needs to be set and you need to call super.init().

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    internal var progressViewController : ProgressViewController        

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        progressViewController = ProgressViewController()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why does he even need the `internal var progressViewController`? If someone needs to pass parameters to a container view controller, I think they should do it through `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: if the `var` wasn't there then yes there wouldn't be a need for an `init` at all

Comment: Now, how can I call a method from `ProgressViewController`? If I want change the text of lables, value of progressview.. ?

Comment: You should do it through `prepareForSegue`

Comment: @Gunaseelan if you are retaining the progressViewController then simply create a method in the ProgressViewController class, and then call it from within the ViewController class with `progressViewController.updateLabels()`

Comment: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: the progressViewController must be initialized and also the labels and progressView within the ProgressViewController before you can call the method